# meaning of this GLM defintion

Tags: generalized-linear-model, link-function

The answer key says "Different link functions have different shapes and can therefore fit to different nonlinear relationships between the predictors and the target variable."

Shouldn't we say "relationships between the **linear** predictors and the **mean** target"?

Comment: "*The answer key says …*" — What is the context for this?  E.g. I haven't the slightest idea what "answer key" the question is referring to.